# Aurelia-ui-framework in webpack

Tags: aurelia-ui-framework

I am trying to configure [aurelia-ui-framework](https://github.com/adarshpastakia/aurelia-ui-framework) in [aspnetcore-spa](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices), but couldn't find any useful method. I have tried the following method.
1. Install packages,

```
"aurelia-templating-resources": "^1.4.0",
"aurelia-ui-framework": "^3.4.2",
"aurelia-ui-virtualization": "^1.0.0-beta.3.1.0",
"aurelia-validation": "^1.1.1",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
"kramed": "^0.5.6",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"moment": "^2.18.1",
"numeral": "^2.0.6",
```

2. Then configure in boot.ts

   aurelia.use
       .standardConfiguration()
       .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-validation'), (config: UIConfig) => { })
       .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-ui-virtualization'))
       .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-ui-framework'));
3. Add some configuration in webpack.config.js

   new ModuleDependenciesPlugin(
               {
                   'aurelia-ui-framework': ['./elements/core/ui-grid', './elements/core/ui-page', './elements/core/ui-viewport', './elements/inputs/ui-button', './elements/inputs/ui-date', './elements/inputs/ui-form', './elements/inputs/ui-input', './elements/inputs/ui-lists', './elements/inputs/ui-markdown', './elements/inputs/ui-options', './elements/inputs/ui-phone', './elements/inputs/ui-textarea', './elements/components/ui-alerts', './elements/components/ui-bars', './elements/components/ui-breadcrumb', './elements/components/ui-datagrid', './elements/components/ui-dg-columns', './elements/components/ui-drawer', './elements/components/ui-dropdown', './elements/components/ui-menu', './elements/components/ui-panel', './elements/components/ui-sidebar', './elements/components/ui-tab', './elements/components/ui-tree'],
                   'aurelia-ui-virtualization': ['./virtual-repeat', './infinite-scroll-next'],
               }

but still didn't find any luck...

Comment: I had a problem loading `aurelia-ui-framework` with a loader other than `requireJS`.
I'll try to get to the bottom of it.. hopefully I'll come up with a solution.

Comment: I am trying me best to come up with a solution that how to configure `aurelia-ui-framewrok` in `webpack`. hopefully it will be helpful.

Comment: more info [here](https://github.com/adarshpastakia/aurelia-ui-framework/issues/75)